# doubly linked list implementation c++

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I'm testing my doubly linked list and it doesn't display anything.
I'm inserting a student data then trying to display it.
I've only worked on the push function and display just to take it by steps.
I'm new to doubly linked lists.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


 class student
{
 public:
int id;            //student ID number
string name;       //student’s name
string university; //student’ university
double GPA;         //student’ GPA
};


//student list is a doubly linked list of students.
class studentList
{
private:
    class node
{
public:
    student data;
    node * next;
    node * prev;
};

node * head;

public:
studentList()
{

    head = NULL;

}

//be sure to free all dynamically allocated memory!
~studentList()
{
    delete head;
}

//return true if the list is empty, false if not
bool empty()
{
    if ( head == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;

}

//insert student s into the front of the linked list
void push(student s)
{
    node *tmp;
    tmp = new node;

    tmp->data = s;
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
}

//remove and return the student at the front of the list
student pop();

//locate and remove the student with given ID number
void removeStudent(int id);

//locate and return a copy of the student with given ID number
student getStudent(int id);

//locate the student with given ID number in list and set their GPA to gpa
void updateGPA(int id, double gpa);

//arrange students into increasing order based on either ID, name, or GPA.  If
//variable 'field' has value "id", sort into increasing order by id.
//If 'field' has value "name", sort into alphabetical order by name.
//If 'field' has value "GPA", sort into order by GPA.
void sort(string field);

//a test function to simply display the list of students to the screen
//in the order they appear in the list.
void display()
{
    node *current = head;

    while (current!=NULL)
    {
        cout << &current->data << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

};

```
int main()
{
studentList *my;
student *edwin;
edwin->name = "edwin";
edwin->university = "lsu";
edwin->GPA = 4.0;
edwin->id = 33;
my->push(*edwin);
my->display();









return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is it _double_-linked? I'd say it's a _single_-linked list.

Comment: What does the constructor of `node` do?

Comment: It would be easier if you showed a complete program, not just bits of it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem exists here, cout << &current->data << endl;

what exactly is data? is it some encapsulated structure? I am assuming it is the entire student struct. If that is the case, then you need to get at that struct and then cout it's various members.
i.e.
cout << &current->data->name << endl;

That is if data is of type student* if it is not, then you need to dereference the pointer to your student struct and then cout it's members.

Also what you have here is not a doubly-linked list, but is infact a single linked list. Doubly-Linked lists have a both next and prev pointer to the next and previous nodes in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing `edwin` properly. The line

```
student *edwin;
```

just declares a pointer to a `student` struct. It does not allocate memory for it. Using `edwin->name` immediately after that is incorrect.

Just use struct instead of a pointer to it `student edwin; edwin.name="...";`.
Your `push` copies the struct anyway.

As noticed by 40two, you are not initializing `my` either. I'd advise you to try to find the correct way to initialize it yourself.

Another place that is likely wrong:

```
cout << &current->data << endl;
```

Can you explain this line? Why don't you do `cout << current->data.name`?

Also note that you never set `prev` pointer in `node` (although you have this field). So it's not a correct double-linked list (it's single-linked, essentially).

Comment: Actually he is not initializing it at all. Nor does initialize `my`.